# Storyboards - initWithCoder gets called twice

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard

Important thing to know I guess is that I am using Storyboards. I am doing the following in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

FirstView *mvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];
SecondView *tvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self addNavigationToViewController:mvc], [self addNavigationToViewController:tvc], nil];

// add controllers to a table view
UITabBarController *tb = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tb setViewControllers:controllers];

[self.window setRootViewController:tb];
```

**addNavigationToViewController** is a method I am using in order to embed a view controller inside a UINavigationController

When I run this app the `initWithCoder` in the **FirstView** is called twice. I found the reason but I don't know how to do it the right way.

Basically the FirstView is getting initialized once due to it being *Initial Scene* ( there is a checkmark in the Attributes Inspector that sets the view "Is initial view controller" ) and the second time:

```
FirstView *mvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];
```

If I uncheck *Initial Scene* it complains that "perhaps the designated entry point is not set".

I am doing something wrong but I have no clue what it is.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem ... while I never call "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" method. I'm using a "pure" storyboard (e.g. no controller is instantiated in source code). Any idea why "initWithCoder" method is called twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an application using storyboards, on app launch, UIKit looks in the info plist for the [the UIMainStoryboardFile key](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW9). If it is set UIKit references that storyboard and uses -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] to create a default root view controller to attach to the window.

UIKit is doing that, and then later in -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, you're also creating a new instance of your view controller. This is why it is being instantiated twice.

If you'd like to completely customize this process, and it looks like you do, then you probably don't want UIKit to take those default actions on your behalf. You can simply remove the UIMainStoryboardFile key(s) from your info.plist, and in your override of -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, you can:

1. Create a window
2. Grab the storyboard
3. Instantiate view controller(s) from the storyboard.
4. Set the root view controller for the window.
5. Make the window key and visible.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some reason beyond what you've mentioned you probably don't need to call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` at all. If you are using storyboards, in most cases you can(should) define your `UITabBarController`'s view controllers in your storyboard and have your `MainTabBarController` be your 'Initial View Controller'. You would also embed your View Controllers in Navigation Controllers in the storyboard.

Comment: Partially true. I can do everything visually but there should be a valid way of doing things with code only. Storyboards are nice but I like them for the fact that they're keeping UI stuff in one place. Your answer gave me an idea though and I'll try it next. Thanks